# Storing all possible combinations of a string when only specific characters

Tags: javascript, typescript, combinations

I am trying to substitute letters of the alphabet with numbers that look similar in style in typescript. I.e The letter I to 1. I have a working function named replaceLettersWithNumber which completes this with all letters, however, I am struggling to grasp and achieve a working solution where it extends from just, Hello -> H3llo -> Hell0, to finally, H3ll0.

The Function named howManyNumberLookingCharacters is called first, and the returned arrays are parameters in the bottom function. I am new to StackOverflow so please let me know if there is any more information I can provide. I feel like this is fairly straightforward, however my brain is not co-operating! Thanks.

```
const replacementLetters = ['O', 'I', 'E', 'A', 'T'];
const replacementNumbers = ['0', '1', '3', '4', '7'];


export function howManyNumberLookingCharacters(stringToBeRead: string): {alphabeticalCharacterPosition: number[], alphabeticalCharacter: string[]} {
let alphabeticalCharacterPosition: number[] = [];
let alphabeticalCharacter: string[] = [];

for (let x = 0; x < stringToBeRead.length; x++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < replacementLetters.length; i++) {
        if (stringToBeRead.toLocaleUpperCase().charAt(x) == replacementLetters[i]) {
            alphabeticalCharacterPosition.push(x);
            alphabeticalCharacter.push(replacementLetters[i])
        }
    }
}
return {alphabeticalCharacterPosition, alphabeticalCharacter};
}


export function replaceLettersWithNumber(stringToBeRead: string, alphabeticalCharacterPosition: number[], alphabeticalCharacter: string[]): string[] {

let stringArray: string[] = [];
for (let x = 0; x < alphabeticalCharacter.length; x++) {
    var indexInArray = replacementLetters.indexOf(alphabeticalCharacter[x].toString());
    stringArray[x] = stringToBeRead.slice(0, alphabeticalCharacterPosition[x]) + replacementNumbers[indexInArray] + stringToBeRead.slice(alphabeticalCharacterPosition[x] + 1);
}
return stringArray;
}
```

Comment: what is the wanted result?

Comment: So a string would be inputted, like Hello, and it would return an array containing, H3llo, Hell0, then H3ll0. The characters to be replaced are in the constant at the top. To make it easier, a longer word would be: Helloo, so that would return: H3lloo, Hell0o, Hello0, H3ll0o, H3llo0 and finally H3ll00.

Comment: Got it, so you want all possible combinations of replacements. Why would you want that? Looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve? Is it something akin to a profanity filter but you want to block all possible combinations?

Comment: @tao Hey, it's for a tool I'm working on. All possible combinations would be great, but the only characters to be replaced are the ones in the constants above, if that makes any sense.

Comment: *"All possible combinations would be great"* careful. You're looking at exponential growth here. For example, your first sentence: `I am trying to substitute letters of the alphabet with numbers that look similar in style in typescript.` has 41 possible replacements, that makes `2199023255552` possible combinations. You can't even create an Array that big.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, that's definitely something to take into consideration.. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to generate combinations is to use recursion.

At each level where a replacement is available, you call the function with both versions, like this:

```
const replacementNumbers = {
  'O': '0', 
  'I': '1', 
  'E': '3', 
  'A': '4', 
  'T': '7',
};

function replacementCombinations(input: string): string[] {
  const uppercase = input.toUpperCase()
  const combinations: string[] = []

  function r(str: string): void{
    if(str.length >= input.length){
      combinations.push(str)
      return
    }

    r(str + input[str.length])

    if(uppercase[str.length] in replacementNumbers)
      r(str + replacementNumbers[uppercase[str.length]])
  }
  r('')
  return combinations
}
```

Note that this code assumes that you're doing single character replacements.

Comment: While this does convert everything, it does turn lowercase to uppercase which I don't think it should do. The result should be Hell0o not HELL0O.

Comment: @MathewBerg Now I see OP's code converted only before mapping. Fixed.

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks for the quick change.

Comment: Looks great, really appreciate it. Thank you.